# How can I interpret an E4X property as a Date in Flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, e4x

I've got XML that looks like this:

```
<item>
     <itemDate>07/10/2009</itemDate>
</item>
```

I would like to be able to read this in as an E4X object: `item.itemDate`  and have `itemDate` be an ActionScript `Date` object instead of a string.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, Nope.  Everything that comes in as XML will be a string - even other primitives like "1", or "false".

When I have to deal with something like this, I iterate through the XML and create a mirroring Object (sometimes an untyped Object, even) and convert the String values to their appropriate datatypes.

Or, I just convert the value to its appropriate datatype just before use.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the value to the [Date constructor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Date.html#Date()):

```
for each(var itemNode:XML in doc.item)
{
    var itemDate : Date = new Date(itemNode.itemDate);
}
```

Comment: Will that work?  Really?  The itemDate object there isn't truly a String; it's an XML object Text node.  Is that going to work?

Comment: Try it and see. The AVM does a substantial amount of implicit coercions. If it doesn't work, just change it to itemNode.itemDate.toString()